# HTML 5 video background repeat EDIT: refreshes

Tags: html, video, background

I used a video as background for my site, the problem is that it's refreshes itself everytime a `<a href="?page=XX">other page</a>` is clicked.

On which way do i prevend this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the kind of video background plugin I use: http://syddev.com/jquery.videoBG/

Till now I believe it's the best option. Try giving it a chance, it will solve your problem, since the plugin prevents that from happening.

Any other doubt feel free to ask in comments!

Greeting from Argentina!

Comment: Welcome! Hope you can figure everything out. Luck!